# unable to push source folders from eclipse to GIT

Tags: eclipse, git

steps I have followed

1. created a repository
2. convert to maven project(configure -> convert to maven project)
3. added facet nature.
4. created folder structure (src/main/java, src/main/resources, src/test/java, src/test/resources)

After that right click on the **project -> GIT bash terminal**

git init

git commit -m "first commit"

git remote add origin URL

git push -u origin master

After doing all this when I do a checkout(clone repository -> import projects) I am unable to see the source folder like src/main/java.
screen shots attached

project created with folder structure

[image]

**folder structure when I did a checkout**

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you do `git add .` after init the repo?

Comment: yes I did add . , add all ,  add *

Comment: `After doing all this when I do a checkout` ... git checkout of _what_?  Also, your first two screenshots are identical.  I'm not sure what the problem is here.

Comment: Changed it please check it now

Answer (score 0):

A git checkout is used to change the branch you are currently working on. It's probably not what you are willing to do here, is it?

My guess regarding your issue is that your git commit didn't commit your newly created files because they were not tracked when you committed your changes.

When you perform a git init, it basically inits a new empty repository, which means that your files are not tracked by default. You first need to git add them before committing.

My explanation is a bit confusing but I guess that if you first git add your files and then commit, it should work.

EDIT: You don't seem to be talking about git checkout here, but rather cloning. This gives even more sense to my answer, I pretty much think that your files have never been committed because you never added them to the staging area.

Comment: I am trying to push the whole project structure and then after clone -> import project will be able to see the workspace with folder structure

Comment: Then I think you are doing it wrong. The steps to follow should be these ones instead: 1. git init - 2. git add * - 3. git commit -m "YourMessage" - 4. git remote add origin URL - 5. git push -u origin master